# Chrome display issue with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using display:flex , 
I'm working with a ul list of elements. Don't know Why i get 2 different Result : 
Problem issue with chrome : 
[Browsers_Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh9IU.jpg)
This is what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/0fbdgfcq/26/

```
    ul {
    max-width:800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding:0;
}

.box{
/* Clean */

}
.g p{
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:3vw;
}
.g li {
    flex: 1 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
    color:white;
    font-size:3vw;
    list-style-type: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}
.g img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:100px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand I'd say the problem is the `width:15%` you have applied which is overriding the flexing of the list items.

Try

```
.g li {
    flex: 1 0 15%;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0fbdgfcq/29/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
ul {
   Position: relative;
 }

   .g p { 
   Position: relative
  }
```

This is to prevent your paragraph from overflowing.

That might fix the issue.

If not try adding it to your `li` as well.